# Retrieve a List of work Item Type from Project and Team iteration area using API

Tags: c#, api, tfs

I want to get all work item Type from Iteration Team Area . 
Here my Sample code

```
 List  = (from WorkItemType WIT 
            in WorkItemStore.Projects[cmbProjects.SelectedIndex].WorkItemTypes 
        select WIT.Name).ToList();
```

This code working fine, but i want to get only project Team and member work item type and work item.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to invoke [witadmin commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx) to list the names of the work item types in the specified project:

```
witadmin listwitd /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project
```